# Strange PHP upload behavior

Tags: php, variables, upload, null

I am having a strange PHP issue that I can't solve by myself. I already tried everything I know.

I have a music upload website. The upload form has some fields (Music, band, subgenre, notes, upload [the file], and genre [this is the once field that the user don't need to write anything, automatic]. The fields "music" and "files" ***CANNOT BE NULL***.

Well, many musics are uploaded normally but some of them causes the strange behavior.

**THE PROBLEM:**

Even filling all the fields (including the "music" and "files", or course), shows me the message (written by me in the script) "Please, feel at least the music name". But i wrote it!
THEN, I tested if the `$_POST` variables are being set, and everytime happens this error, any `$_POST`/`$_GET` variables are null. This happens specially if the music takes more time to be uploaded.
Also, NO PHP ERRORS HAPPENS. Nothing.

**NOTES:**

- I already tried `set_time_limit(0);`
- I already changed the `max_upload_size` and the other one, I had the size problem before and I solved it. The max is 20mb and the music i'm trying upload is just 9mb.
- I already did the `print_r($_POST)` and returns to me "array ()", nothing.

Here is my code, if you want to see it:

I'm pretty sure that the error is in `PHP.ini`, I tried:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', '3600');
ini_set('max_input_time', '3600');
```

But most of the times, `ini_set` doesn't work.

How to solve it?

**EDIT:**

The queries on the form script file are not important for the upload.

Comment: Can you show the HTML used for the form? If your POST is empty, somehow your request can't have sent it... I would look for the error there.

Comment: Yes i can, wait a second. I will edit here.

Comment: What does the `$_FILES["post_arquivo"]["error"]` says? Try print it. Might help.

Comment: also how are you running php? I mean the webservice and SO, for example I had a similar issue running IIS7 php5.3 on fastCGI, and besides max_execution_time() I had to set fastCGI's request timeout as well.

Comment: maybe it is because of post_max_size?

Comment: @MarkTopper, i did this: $x = $_FILES["post_arquivo"]["error"]; $y = $_FILES['post_arquivo']['name']; echo "$x e $y"; and the echo just return the "e". The both variables are null/empty.

Comment: @aleation i'm running the script in a host. Probably is the most recent. Also, how can i change the max_execution_time? I tried ini_set but most of the times it doesn't work.

sedatsevgili No, the music is 9mb and the max_upload_size is 20mb. I already had this problem before and i solved.

Comment: the way you did it on the code should work, try to do it from your hosting anyway as well, normally they should provide you some way to do it, contact your hosting if you can't, or switch to another xDD. take the ob_start and similars from your code, it could be causing issues as well. And last thing, usually I put echoes on some different points of the code to see where do it stop, maybe it helps you debugging.

Comment: @aleation That's right. On localhost, any music is uploaded normally. I'm pretty sure that the problem is the php.ini (like the problem i had before with "max_upload_size". I tried many echos, but no errors found. Also i did the error_reporting(E_ALL);, no errors as well. Maybe the problem is with the ob_start, but i need it cause cookies are being set. I will try contact the host, probably they can help, but they don't give a support to third parties. My host is DreamHost, they are pretty good. I don't know what hell is going on...

Comment: @aleation I tried remove the ob_start/ob_end_flush and also the cookie, but no sucess.

Comment: This might be an issue to your PHP.ini setting post_max_size. Not just the upload size try increasing it to 100mb and see if that works. had a similar issue with an array and it turned out it was the post_max_size.

Comment: @Ryan I will try to increase it, just a momment.

Comment: @Ryan How can i modify the max_upload_size and the post_max_size? It's on the server and i can't modify the php.ini file properly. How can i modify it without open the php.ini?

Comment: You can't change the post_max_size on the fly. You need to have that option set in the ini file. same goes for max_upload_size

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to modify the php upload size or post size (assuming that is what is causing the issue which sounds likely) it may be worth looking at some sort of chunked upload solution. Something like http://www.plupload.com/ may be worth taking a look at.

This will allow you to keep the chunks uploaded below the servers upload limit and then rebuild the file serverside after it has finished uploading. At also allows you to show quite a neat little progress bar to the user whilst they are waiting.

It has various runtimes including html5 and requires very little configuration to get it working. The only thing you will need to do is change the flow of the form submission process. So catch the form submit, trigger the upload using plupload and then when the upload is complete post the rest of the form data.

I know it's not a direct solution to the issue you are having but it's a good alternative that may avoid some of the issues you're having.